# Не срабатывает функция "onclick". Что я сделал не так? Ошибка в консоле "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null "

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function () {
    
    var text = document.querySelector('p.offer');
    text.classList.add('red');

    var img = document.querySelector ('.img');
    img.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ошибка у вас не в onclick а в установке стилей для "p.offer". Проверьте, переменную text. Находит ли этот элемент функция

Comment: Это значт что не нашло елемент `p.offer`

Comment: если text равен ``undefined`` то да, элемент который вы ищите не найден

Comment: добавьте ``console.log(text)`` перед добавлением класса элементу

Comment: Спасибо))) Заработало!
Ошибка была в стилях "p.offer"
Интересно почему тогда не срабатывало вторая часть кода?
 var img = document.querySelector ('.img');
    img.style.display = 'none';

Comment: @MaxDuma, после фатальной ошибки, все что ниже не работает. Для этого лучше всего использовать `if(text){ ..// }`

Comment: Надо привыкать к тому что даже для самого элементарного кода создавать обертку try catch. и обрабатывать все данные приходящие из вне через if. null, undefined, "", ``. '' в node.js принимается как false так что if() не позволит допустить ошибку. а фатальные ошибки это потенциальная уязвимость... если они не обрабатываются

Comment: Понял, Спасибо)